# MongoDb aggregation from simple to nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a problem with MongoDb. I need to nest to documents but I am not able to do it. Can someone help me?

Below my structure:

**Manufacturer:**

```
{_id:'2323dewegfwef',
 id:1,
 name:'manufacturer'}
```

**Brand:**

```
{_id:'234234dsgfwef',
 id:1,
 name:'brand',
 products:[
             {_id:'23423sdfsdf',
              id:1,
              brandId:1,
              manufacturerId:1},

             {_id:'23423sdfsdf',
              id:2,
              brandId:1,
              manufacturerId:1}

           ]
```

}

I would like to merge both collections and make a result like this:

**Manufacturer:**

```
{_id:345345regsfdg,
 id:1,
 name:'manufacturer',
 brands:[
             {_id:'234234dsgfwef',
              id:1,
              name:'brand1',
              products:[
                        {_id:'23423sdfsdf',
                         id:1,
                         brandId:1,
                         manufacturerId:1},

                        {_id:'23423sdfsdf',
                         id:2,
                         brandId:1,
                         manufacturerId:1}
                        ]
             },
             {_id:'234234dsgfwef',
              id:2,
              name:'brand2',
              products:[
                        {_id:'23423sdfsdf',
                         id:3,
                         brandId:2,
                         manufacturerId:1},

                        {_id:'23423sdfsdf',
                         id:4,
                         brandId:2,
                         manufacturerId:1}
                        ]
             }
       ]
```

}

**Attempt:**

```
db.Manufacturer.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:'Brand',localField:'id',foreignField:'products.manufacturerId',as:'brands'}}])
```

I have tried multiple combinations with $lookup, $group, $push $unwind ...
but I did not find the key.

Some help?

Thanks

Comment: *"I have tried multiple combinations..."* - Yet we don't see any attempt at code in the question. Perhaps you should show what you have tried and then someone can use that as a guide to point out what you got wrong. Without a code attempt in the question it "looks like" you simply want someone to write your code for you. I'm sure that's not the case, so we would like to see your attempted code, even if it's failing.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to added it. Thanks for the advice